# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 2

Tags: python, json, django

For several hours now I have been crazily trying to get and display json data externally using `JSON.parse` but am having this error below

> ```
>  VM935:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 2
>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>     at Object.<anonymous> ((index):698)
>     at fire (jquery-3.3.1.js:3268)
>     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.js:3398)
>     at done (jquery-3.3.1.js:9305)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.js:9548)
> ```

Here is my code and effort so far. can somebody help me fix this issue. I will appreciate.

### tacker.html

```
{% load static %}
{% block title %}
Shop - Tracker
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<section>
    <center>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 p-b-30">
                    <form class="leave-comment" method="POST" id="trackerForm" action="#">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <h4 class="m-text26 p-b-36 p-t-15">
                            Track Your order
                        </h4>
                        <div class="bo4 of-hidden size15 m-b-20">
                            <input class="sizefull s-text7 p-l-22 p-r-22" id="orderId" type="text" name="orderId" placeholder="Order Id" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="bo4 of-hidden size15 m-b-20">
                            <input class="sizefull s-text7 p-l-22 p-r-22" id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="w-size25">
                            <!-- Button -->
                            <button class="flex-c-m size2 bg1 bo-rad-23 hov1 m-text3 trans-0-4">
                                Track your Order
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 p-b-30">
                <h4 class="m-text26 p-b-36 p-t-15">
                    Track order
                </h4>
                <ul class="list-group" id="track">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 p-b-30">
                <h4 class="m-text26 p-b-36 p-t-15">
                    Your order Details
                </h4>
                <ul class="list-group" id="citem">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
<script>
$('#trackerForm').submit(function(event) {
    $('#track').empty();
    var formData = {
        'orderId': $('input[name=orderId]').val(),
        'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/shop/tracker/',
            data: formData,
            encode: true
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            updates = data[0];
            if (updates.length > 0 & updates != {}) {

                for (i = 0; i < updates.length; i++) {
                    let text = updates[i]['text'];
                    let time = updates[i]['time'];
                    mystr = '<li class="list-group-item"> ${text} <span class="badge"> ${time} </span></li>'
                    $('#track').append(mystr);

                }
            } else {
                mystr = 'sorry'
                $('#track').append(mystr);
            }
            //fill in the order Details
            cart = JSON.parse(data[1]);
            console.log(cart);
            for (item in cart) {
                let name = cart[item][1];
                let qty = cart[item][0];
                mystr = '<li class="list-group-item">${name}<span class="badge">${qty}</span></li>'
                $('#citem').append(mystr);
            }


        });
    event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

### models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    items_json = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=111)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=111, default="")

    def __str__(self,):
        return self.name


class OrderUpdate(models.Model):
    update_id  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_id = models.IntegerField(default="")
    update_desc = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.update_desc[0:7] + "..."
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Order, OrderUpdate
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse


def tracker(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        orderId = request.POST.get('orderId', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        return HttpResponse(f"{orderId} and {email}")
        try:
            order = Orders.objects.filter(order_id=orderId, email=email)
            if len(order)>0:
                update = OrderUpdate.objects.filter(order_id=orderId)
                updates = []
                for item in update:
                    updates.append({'text': item.update_desc, 'time': item.timestamp})
                    response = json.dumps([updates, order[0].item_json], default=str)
                return HttpResponse(response)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('{}')
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse('{}')

    return render(request, 'shop/tracker.html')
```

Comment: It's simply invalid JSON, that's what the error is telling you. What have you done to try and troubleshoot/figure out why it's invalid?

Comment: Why are you assigning `response` each time through the `for` loop? You're just overwriting what you assigned the previous time?

Comment: Barmar makes a good point. @MikeK is right though. Without the JSON data, how can we solve anything?

Comment: You may want to learn about the `JsonResponse` class too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tracker()` isn't returning JSON. It returns when it executes

```py
return HttpResponse(f"{orderId} and {email}")
```

and never executes the code that creates JSON in `response` and does

```py
return HttpResponse(response)
```

Get rid of that first `return` line.

Also, the assignment

```py
response = json.dumps([updates, order[0].item_json], default=str)
```

should be after the `for` loop, not inside it.